# What is the usage of adding an empty string in a javascript statement

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I see an empty string (`''` or `""`) used in many JavaScript statements but not sure what does it stand for.

e.g. `var field = current.condition_field + '';`

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Number to String; `(""+5) + 1 == 51`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Type Casting**.
It converts the type to `string`

If variable `current.condition_field` is not of `string` type, by adding `''` using `+` operator at the end/beginning of it converts it to `string`.

```
var field = current.condition_field + '';
```

So, `field` is always `string`.

**Example**

```js
var bool = true; // Boolean
var str = bool + ''; // "true"

document.write('bool: ' + typeof bool + '<br />str: ' + typeof str);


var num = 10; // Numeric
var str = num + ""; // "10"

document.write('<br /><br />num: ' + typeof num + '<br />str: ' + typeof str);
```

Thanks to @KJPrice:

> This is especially useful when you want to call a `string` method(Method defined on `string prototype`) on that variable.

```
(myVar + '').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This is especially useful when you are planning on using a String method on your variable: `(someVariable + '').toUpperCase()`