# understanding modenizer contains Function

Tags: javascript, operators, modernizr

i was just going through the code of modenizer and came across the following function :

```
function contains(str, substr) {
    return !!~('' + str).indexOf(substr);
}
```

modenizer has alot of such small function for small tests. now coming to my question , i do understand that double equal is for converting everything to boolean value , but what is `!!~` for also what is the

```
''
```

before the `str` for ??

i have seen a few questions on SO that address similar issues but not exactly this issue , can somebody explain whats happening inside this function in the context of this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!~('' + str)`

1. `!!`: Converts to boolean(`true/false`)
2. `~`: [**Bitwise NOT**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) Unary operator operates by reversing all the bits in the operand. Inverts the bits of its operand.

   **Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1).**
3. [`'' + str`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980951/2025923): **Type Casting** Converts str to `string`

The operator first casts `str` to `string` then reverses the all the bits of binary and then returns the boolean result.

**EXAMPLE**

```
contains('abcd', 'd');

1. If str is not string then it is converted to string

    true + '' // "true"
    1 + ''    // "1"

2. `indexOf`
    The index of `substr` is returned.

3. `~`
    The bitwise NOT of 3 which is -(3 + 1) = -4

4. `!!`
    !!-4 = true


true will be returned.
```

Comment: Thanks genious ! on last request can you give a couple of examples of `~` ? . Thanks you

Comment: @Tenali_raman See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT

Comment: @Tenali_raman I've added step by step explanation of how `contains` work

Answer (score 2):

Nice thing. ~x is bitwise not. For -1 bitwise not is 0. So !!~ means 'is not -1' in boolean representation.