# The way to increase variable

Tags: javascript

```
foo.setAttribute("item-position", ""+bar+"");
```

The `bar` variable is a number, for example 1 or 15. What's the way to increase it on 1, so it would be 2 and 16 ?

May be something like this? But it doesn't work.

```
foo.setAttribute("item-position", ""+bar+""+1);
// The result should be 2 and 16, but here the result is 21 and 161.
// That is not what I want.
```

Comment: Don't use quotes, use `(+bar) + 1`. For reference [What is the usage of adding an empty string in a javascript statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980931/what-is-the-usage-of-adding-an-empty-string-in-a-javascript-statement/30980951)

Comment: It does not work because you treat `bar` as a text string. Use parentheses to evaluate it before forcing it to string representation.

Comment: @Tushar: While that's true, it will immediately be turned into a string. Attribute values are *always* strings. In any case, the OP said it was already a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently appending the number to the end of the string, this has nothing to do with arithmetic.

Just add the calculated result

```
foo.setAttribute("item-position", bar+1);
```

You don't have to turn it into a string, `setAttribute` will do that part.

Or if you want to increase the value in `bar` *and* show it, use the preincrement operator:

```
foo.setAttribute("item-position", ++bar);
```