# Why must functions have variables that equal to the sum of itself and an empty string

Tags: javascript

In this code:

```
function reverse_a_number(n)
{
    n = n + "";
    return n.split("").reverse().join("");
}
console.log(Number(reverse_a_number(32243)));
```

Its function is supposed to reverse any number.

Why must "n" be equal to ' n + "" '?

In the return statement why must the split and join methods have an empty string and not reverse?

Why can't the code be like the one written below (I know it would read error, but I want understand why)?

```
function reverse_a_number(n)
{
return n.split().reverse().join();
}

console.log(Number(reverse_a_number(32243)));
```

Comment: It's a short way to coerce a value into a string. Similar to how `!` and `+` can coerce values to booleans and numbers, respectively.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980931/what-is-the-usage-of-adding-an-empty-string-in-a-javascript-statement

Comment: Check out the docs for [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to understand which use parameters and what they mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why must `n` be equal to `n + ""`?

```
n = n + "";
```

is equivalent to

```
n = String(n);
```

This is needed because `split()` is a string method, it doesn't work with numbers.

> In the return statement why must the split and join methods have an empty string and not reverse?

You have to give a separator to `split()`. Using an empty string means to turn each character into an element of the result array. If you omit the separator, the default is to put the entire string into a single array element.

For `join()`, the default separator is `,`. So if you left this out you would get `'3,4,2,2,3'` instead of `'34223'`.

`reverse()` doesn't have any parameters. It simply reverses the array that it's called on, there are no options.

Comment: Very very useful!